# Eslint flagging the first function definition in a Vue file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I am writing a Vue file with a Typescript script, and getting a bizarre Eslint “error”.

[image]

The complaint on line 15 is `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

It happens with the first function definitions, wherever it appears in the file, and not on subsequent definitions.  The problem seems insensitive to any change in the template above it.

Comment: Have you told ESLint you're expecting that to include types? In JS there'd have to be a comma before the second parameter...

Comment: The question lacks eslint config, which is the subject here. The error means that it's parsed as JS instead of TS, so the linter was misconfigured

Comment: why have you define the type of r as number in the function and then you have passed string by calling a("3")?

Comment: @rebinnaf — I wanted to make certain that the code really was being processed as Typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you've configured ESLint for TypeScript?
The error suggests it is expecting JavaScript, and types and other TS features, are not valid JS.

---

You need to use `@typescript-eslint` in your eslint config file.

For example, in `.eslintrc.json` (or `.eslintrc`, or in YAML format), use something similar to:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "@vue/typescript/recommended"
  ]
}
```

And ensure you've got the required libraries installed:

```sh
yarn add -D eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @vue/typescript/recommended
```

(`@typescript-eslint/parser` is the parser, `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` contains some standard linting rules for TS, `@vue/typescript/recommended` is the Vue specific rules, and ofc `eslint` is the core ESLint library.)

Comment: I had wrongly assumed that since after the first error, everything was working correctly, that ESLint for TypeScript was configured properly.  Nope.
I was unable to install (or find at all) `@vue/typescript/recommended` or even `@vue/typescript`.  Other than that, your suggestion worked, and I am accepting it as the answer.